# else error occur in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying approving documents and below is the  code in button which I did it
but here else condition error occur ..any one tell me where is the mistake occur in below code. Is there nay brackets problem or something else????

code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

             string connStr = 
             ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            mySQLconnection.Open();
        }


           for (int i = 0; i < Repeater2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList DropDownListcontrol = 
           ((DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList4"));
            Label DocId = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DocId"));


                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approveddd",mySQLconnection);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                       cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
                            Convert.ToInt32((DocID.Text));

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveID", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
                            Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value 
                     = (Session["Login2"]);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        DMSLIB.Doc myDoc = new DMSLIB.Doc();
                        myDoc.MarkDocAs(Convert.ToInt16(DocId.Text),
                            Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue));
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        apfi.Text = "Error";
                    }
                  if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
               {
                  mySQLconnection.Close();
                }
                }
```

An error occurs in the `else` block:

```
    Invalid expression term 'else'
; expected
```

Comment: If that's the standard of your code formatting, then you're asking for trouble - and not seeing the position of the `else` block (as stated in the 2 answers so far) is exactly what you're going to get. If you were working for me and I saw this, I would reject it immediately!

Answer (score 3):

You must follow Microsoft [guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) . It should be like this :

```
if(condition)
{
}
else
{
}
```

**Not like this**

```
  if(condition)
     {
     }
  for(...........)
     {
     }
  else
     {
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You misplaced else. change your for loop. because you have

```
if()
{
}
for()
{
}
else// belongs to where?
{
}
```